# Perform Arithmetic on Two Adjacent Rows WITHOUT a For Loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

Let's assume I have a 200x10 Matrix of log files (in reality it will be something like 16 Million x 10) and in one of the columns I have a timestamp. I need to calculate the time difference between the row[n] and row [n+1]. Using a for-loop will cause my program to run incredibly slow but is there any other way to solve this problem?

Many Thanks, 
Alex

Comment: Please add a reproducible example and the expected output?

Comment: If you just wanted the difference of adjacent numbers in a column, I'd suggest something like `data$difference <- c(NA, data$col2[-1] - data$col1[-nrow(data)])`. It's hard for me to test when I don't know what format your times are.

Comment: give `?diff` a look to see if that's what you're trying to do.